# Null Value in Parameterised Routes Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular5

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlets' of null**

I, am using Parameterised Routes to pass the id of each item. The route is working perfectly.

```
 { path: 'item/:id', component: SingleItemComponent }

<a class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" [routerLink]="['/item', _genericViewModel.data?.question.questionId]">
```

Since, in the first load of the page the id is empty because the the data is not fetch from the server. The reason I, am getting null `_genericViewModel.data?.question.questionId]` is because of asynchronous call. when it fetch data from the server every thing is working perfect.

How, can I check the null condition on the initial load of the component.

Here is the code for the fetch data from server

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, genericViewModel: GenericResponseObject<SingleItemViewModel>, singleItemService: GenericHttpClientService,) {
        this._genericViewModel = genericViewModel;
        this._singleItemService = singleItemService;
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.getHomeItemHttpCall(params.id));
    }

private getHomeItemHttpCall(id: string): void {

        this._singleItemService.GenericHttpGet<GenericResponseObject<SingleItemViewModel>>(this.GetHomeItemUrl + id).subscribe(data => {
            if (data.isSuccess) {
                this._genericViewModel.data = data.data;
            }

        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

[image: error details]

Here is the error screen shot
[image: error details]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have 3 methods to solve this:

1. Use `*ngIf="_genericViewModel.data"` in the `<a>` tag.
2. Use the `async` pipe in the `routerLink` as follows:

   `[routerLink]="['/item', _genericViewModel.data?.question.questionId | async]"`
3. Use a `resolver`. It is a method by which you can run some logics like data fetching before you route to a specific URL. Use the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) to learn more.

Although I am not sure about the second option but please do try them out and let me know.

Comment: Okay.. thanx for letting me know. Please do mark it as the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: I, don't know that this is the best option to do it..... is their any better way to do it ?

Comment: Is the error coming only on routing? If yes, the you can use a `resolver` to get the data before loading the component itself. I have updated my answer with the same.